# How to show and search a list of products in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to build these functionalities to a project using Asp.Net Core MVC.

Could someone please guide me through, How I can approach these steps:

- View a list of product types for a given product category or for all categories.

I have created an ASP.NET Core MVC project with Identity authentication, where the user could register and log in.
I also have these Models created.

```
namespace Company.Models
{
public class ProductType
{
    public ProductType()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    public long ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductInfo { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public ProductTypeStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string AdminComment { get; set; }
    public Category Categories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; protected set; }
}

public enum ProductTypeStatus
{
    Available,
    ReservedAdmin
}

public enum ProductStatus
{
    Available,
    ReservedLoaner,
    ReservedAdmin,
    Loaned,
    Defect,
    Trashed,
    Lost,
    NeverReturned
}



namespace Company.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public long ProductId { get; set; }
        public long ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        public int ProductNumber { get; set; }
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public ProductStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string AdminComment { get; set; }
        public string UserComment { get; set; }
        public long? CurrentLoanInformationId { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Company.Models
{
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        ProductTypes = new List<ProductType>();
    }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductType> ProductTypes
    {
        get; protected set;
    }
}
```

I have recently turned to Asp.Net Core MVC. So this is a new envirnoment for me to get startd. Though, I did follow the msdn tutorials on asp.net mvc.
I APPRECIATE any help!

Comment: You should ask for specific part. It really hard for everyone to give you an idea when you asking for 3 topic.

Comment: @TonyNgo thanks. I edited the question. I guess it will be a good starting point with the first part.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your model design I think you missing 1 small thing that is relationship between Product and Category.

1 Product will be in 1 Category

So to add 1 to 1 relationship you need to adjust your model like this. You can view more [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration)

```
namespace Company.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public long ProductId { get; set; }
        public long ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        public int ProductNumber { get; set; }
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public ProductStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string AdminComment { get; set; }
        public string UserComment { get; set; }
        public long? CurrentLoanInformationId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get;set; }
    }
}

namespace Company.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            ProductTypes = new List<ProductType>();
        }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProductType> ProductTypes
        {
            get; protected set;
        }
    }
}
```

So when you update your model you will need to run ef migration to apply change to db. Detail can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

And finally you need to write the code to query some thing like

```
var query = _db.Product.Where(x => x.Category == "Book");
```

You can read how to write ef query in c# [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now, the problem was not listed because Category status IsActive false was added and there was a small typo, thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).